# Header and footer change their position after keyboard popup in IOS Using DOJO 1.10.3

Tags: css, iphone, header, mobile-safari, dojox.mobile

We developing **hybride mobile application** with **DOJO 1.10.3**.

In this application have a **header** and **footer**, **all environments** **comming good except IOS(iphone) environment** we getting one problem i.e

We want to **fixed header and footer** in **android,windows and Blackberry** **header(top)** and **footer(down)** is fixed but iphone it's **not fixing** and **content** also **going up** and they **visible** the **text in status bar(battery,signal and time screen)** when i given some value in **input field,text area** etc.

My requirement is fixed and not able scrolling for the header and also not showing in any text in status bar(battery,signal and time screen).

Please any one help for this problem

> CSS CODE

```css
.qHeaderBg h1 {
    height: 42px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
    display: table;
    line-height: 0px;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed !important;
}

.qHeaderBg h2 {
    background: rgba(160, 32, 64, 1.0);
    height: 44px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.0);
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed !important;
}

.qHeaderBg label {
    margin: 12px 8% 5px 7%;
    width: 85%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    display: block;
}

.qHeaderBg input {
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-indent: 10px;
    color: rgba(23, 82, 117, 1.0);
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    height: 34px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: white !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

.qHeaderBg input[type="email"] {
    font-family: Times New Roman;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid rgb(254, 207, 23);
    background-image: none;
}

.button {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 18px auto 0px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 85.5%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 2.4;
    border-radius: 7px;
    outline: none;
}

.marginBottom {
    margin-bottom: 55px !important;
}
```

> HTML code

```html
<div id="Login_en_View" class="qHeaderBg englishFont"
        data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">


<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="Login_en_View_Id"
    data-dojo-props="selected:false" >



    <h1 class="ui-title" id="Login_en_View_Header" data-dojo-          type="dojox.mobile.Heading"b data-dojo-props="fixed:'top'">
    </h1>


    <div id="Login_en_View_DivId" class="ui-content" data-role="content">

        <div class="errorMsg englishFont" id="Login_en_View_Error"></div>

        <div class="successMsg englishFont" id="Login_en_View_Success"></div>

        <label id="Login_en_View_Mno_lbl"></label> 
            <input id="Login_en_View_Mno_txt" class="clearFields englishFont"
                data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==13 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;" type="number" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number"> 

        <label id="Login_en_View_Uc_lbl"></label> 
            <input id="Login_en_View_Uc_txt" class="clearFields englishFont" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox"
                onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==8 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;" type="password" min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" title="Non-negative integral number">  

        <button id="Login_en_View_Sub_Btn" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="englishFont button"></button>

        <button id="Login_en_View_Reg_Btn" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" class="englishFont button"></button>

        <button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id="Login_en_View_Ruc_Btn"  class="englishFont button marginBottom"></button>

    </div>


          <h2  id="Login_en_View_Footer" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
                data-dojo-props="fixed:'bottom'">
    </h2>  




</div>

</div>
```

Comment: any one have a solution please respond